# How to develop server side pagination in java?

Tags: java, search-engine

I have developed a search engine in java. Used java Servlet in server side. The problem is for each query lots of results appears.Each result is represented as a string.
How to achieve server side pagination?

Comment: Please post some code or give detailed information on your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea of the pagination is to using skip/limit parameters. You should set skip/limit parameters into the query in client-side and on the server-side by checking this parameters you should return the expected results.

Explanation of the parameters are :

```
skip : skips the number of results and return the others
limit : return the given number of results.
```

Ex : Say your query returns a 25 result and you want to paginate it.
Then for your first page you should set skip=0, limit=10 on the client-side and on the server-side by checking this parameters you should skip 0 result and return the 10 of them. Then it will return the results between 0-9 for first page.

For second page, you should send query with skip=10, limit=10 and result will be between 10-19.

For last page your query will be skip=20, limit=10 and it will return you the results between 20-25.

This is the general idea how pagination work. To use pagination you should implement it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Spring MCV check this link out: http://blog.fawnanddoug.com/2012/05/pagination-with-spring-mvc-spring-data.html

Most Java Server Frameworks should offer something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation depends on what technology you are using like are you using caching, what DB you are using  and how open are you to use new technologies

lets suppose you want to use servlets only...you can use rownum feature to display the results based on the page number click on your jsp..

if you are open to use new technologies....use springdata, jparespositiry
http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/